# How to Enter Text By User Input in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the user to input data for my TODO App instead of picking up data from a predefined array.

Below is my Parent component

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import todosData from "./todosData"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            todos: todosData
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.nameEnter = this.nameEnter.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(item => {
                if (item.id === id){
                    return {
                         ...item,
                         completed: !item.completed
                    }
                }
                    return item
            })
            return {
                todos: updatedTodos
            }
        })

    }
    nameEnter(){
        var name = this.name
        console.log(name)
        }

    render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item}
        handleChange = {this.handleChange} nameEnter= {this.nameEnter}/>)

        return (
            <div className="todo-list">
                {todoItems}
            </div>
        )    
    }
}
export default App
```

This one is the child component where I have added input fields

```
import React from "react"
function TodoItem(props) {

    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input 
                type = "checkbox" 
                checked = {props.item.completed} 
                onChange = { () => props.handleChange(props.item.id) }    
            />
            <input type = "text" name= "name" />

            <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

This is how my page looks. Instead of predefined text `example:"GROCERRY SHOPPING"`, I want the user to enter text and it should be in place of that.

[image]

Comment: update the text with state and subscribe to that change.

Comment: i have updated my code. Can u please take a look.

Comment: You should use `onChange = { (event) => props.handleChange(event, id) }` in your input. That way your `handleChange` function will receive the `event` object which contains the value through `event.target.value` and the `id` through the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here it is

```
<input onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}/>


//react hooks
const [values,setValues] = useState({inputValue: 'predefined'});
handleChange = (e)=>{
setValues({...values,[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

//classes
handleChange = (e)=>{
this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
}
```

this generic and can apply to a number of inputs, not just one

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react"

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            name: ""
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
      }) 
    }

    render() {
        const {name} = this.state
        return (
            <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        )    
    }
}
export default Form
```

Comment: you can pass the onChange = { (event) => props.handleChange(event, props.item.id) } and use 
**handleChange = (event, id) => {
        console.log(event.target.checked)
    }**

Answer (score 0):

```js
changeInputVal (ev, index) {
        ev.persist();
        const newArr = this.state.inputArrVal;
        newArr[index]=ev.target.value;
        this.setState({inputArrVal:newArr, currentPage:1});   
    }
```

you need to do something like that in TodoItem --
where --
1- inputArrVal:{}  is object And

2-  "this.changeInputVal(event, props.item.id)}/>"